# CAShapeLayer dashed line start with margin

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

Is it possible to start drawing dashed `CAShapeLayer` line with some margin? I am connect couple dashed lines at an angle.

It would be great if my dash could start at half dash length. So if

```
lineDashPattern = [8, 8]
```

then dash line should start drawing with 4 margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [lineDashPhase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521856-linedashphase). It specifies an offset, in user space applied to the line dash pattern

> Line dash phase specifies how far into the dash pattern the line
>   starts.

```
shapeLayer1.lineDashPhase = 8
```

[image]